# Python Generator not giving nex value

Tags: python, function, printing, generator

I am currently messing around with python generators to try to understand them.

I create the following simple function:

```
def simpleGeneratorFun(): 
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    yield 4
```

Then:

```
for value in simpleGeneratorFun(): 
    print(value)
```

It's output, logically, is:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Assigning them to variables seem to work in the exact way.

```
b = simpleGeneratorFun()
print(id(b))
c = simpleGeneratorFun()
print(id(c))
```

Output:

```
122357576
122356552
```

Then:

```
print(next(b))
print(next(c))
print(next(b))
print(next(c))
print(next(b))
print(next(c))
print(next(b))
print(next(c))
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

So i decided to do as follows:

```
print(id(simpleGeneratorFun()),next(simpleGeneratorFun()))
print(id(simpleGeneratorFun()),next(simpleGeneratorFun()))
```

Output:

```
122355912 1
122355912 1
```

Strangely, even though I am calling the exact same function (ensured by de ID) this time it seems it does not saves generators state.

Next thing I tried is:

```
print(id(simpleGeneratorFun()),next(simpleGeneratorFun()),next(simpleGeneratorFun()),next(simpleGeneratorFun()))
```

Output:

```
122355912 1 1 1
```

But if i code this:

```
d = simpleGeneratorFun()
print(id(d),next(d),next(d),next(d),next(d))
```

Output:

```
122355912 1 2 3 4
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it continue the series instead of starting over again?

Comment: `id` has nothing to do with the function you are calling. In any case, each time you call a generator function `simpleGeneratorFun()` it **returns a new generator object**. That's the whole point.

Comment: Then, why calling next on d returns different values while calling next on simplegeneratorfun() doesnt?

Comment: Because `d` is the same object every time you call `next` on it. Every time you do `next(simpleGeneratorFuncion())` you create *a new generator object*, which gets passed to `next`, since it is new, it always starts at the beginning, and since you never keep it round anywhere, it gets garbage collected immediately after

Comment: I thought that the ID function ensured it was the same function. Is just assigning a new generator to the same ID? Is there another way to check this?

Comment: `id` gives you a unique number for the lifetime of an object. You were using `id` but the objects ceased to exist between your calls to `id`, so yes the number was re-used. So try `g1 =simpleGeneratorFuncion(); g2  =simpleGeneratorFuncion(); print(g1 ==g2`, or more simply, `simpleGeneratorFuncion() is simpleGeneratorFuncion()`, but honestly, this is a fundamental aspect of how generator functions work.